# Simple question on UIAlertView and UIAlertViewDelegate

Tags: iphone, delegates, uialertview, uiactionsheet

I hope this is pretty straight-forward.  As you'll see by my code, I'm simply trying to get a UIAlertView button-press to pop me back to the root view.

I don't get any compile errors or warnings, and when I run the app, the "RedeemCoupon" method is called in the IBAction, and the UIAlertView pops up as it should, but it doesn't seem the "doneRedeeming" method gets called at all - I don't see anything from NSLog (yes I'm aware that I am setting buttonIndex to 0 - once I get this working I'll fix it).  So, basically it doesn't work.  I click the "cancel" button and the alert just goes away.

By the way I'm not sure if this matters, but this "RedeemCouponViewController" view is number 4 on the stack, and it was added by use of presentModalViewController in the previous view.

I'm open to other ways of doing this if needed - all suggestions welcome!

Thanks in advance!

```
// RedeemCouponViewController.h

@interface RedeemCouponViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate> {
```

---

```
//  RedeemCouponViewController.m

- (IBAction) redeemYes: (UIButton*) sender {    
    CouponRedeem *redeem = [[CouponDatabase database] couponRedeem:_uniqueId];
    [redeem release];

    UIAlertView *doneRedeeming = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Coupon Redeemed!"
                                                           message:@"Thanks for shopping!" 
                                                          delegate:self 
                                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"Back to Main Menu" 
                                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [doneRedeeming show];
    [doneRedeeming release];
  }

-(void) doneRedeeming: (UIAlertView *) doneRedeeming clickedButtonAtIndex: (NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex = 0) {
       NSLog(@"doneRedeemed method called");
       [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    } else {
       //do nothing
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to have

```
if (buttonIndex == 0) {
```

in place of

```
if (buttonIndex = 0) {
```

The former checks for equality whereas the latter assigns.

Also, you want to have

```
– alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:
```

where you have

```
- doneRedeeming:clickedButtonAtIndex:
```

Comment: Yes, thanks - I know it's not correct, but I just wanted to be sure the statement was true for now just in case "Cancel" wasn't "0" for some reason.  Thanks for the tip, though!

Comment: As a side note it's often safer to write that comparison as `(0 == buttonIndex)` this way the program won't compile if you do accidently assign instead of comparing and you have avoided a potential logic error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `UIAlertViewDelegate` [methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html):

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {}
```

not

```
-(void) doneRedeeming: (UIAlertView *) doneRedeeming clickedButtonAtIndex: (NSInteger)buttonIndex {}
```

Comment: Tried your change (actually I had it this way initially, but it didn't work :-(

Answer (score 0):

Use the delegate method `-alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` to listen for your cancel button index

Comment: Tried this: '-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex: (NSInteger)buttonIndex {
 if (buttonIndex = 0) {
  NSLog(@"doneRedeemed method called");
  [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 } else {
  //do nothing
 }
}'  Still not working <sad face>

Comment: Should `if (buttonIndex = 0)` be `if (buttonIndex == 0)`?

Comment: Yes, you're right it should be - I just wanted to eliminate that as a possible error so I just set it manually for now.

Comment: Then if your delegate method isn't getting called, your delegate isn't set properly. Check where you set your delegate.

Comment: Okay, well the only thing I've done is include "<UIAlertViewDelegate>" in the header file.  Is there something more I should be doing?

Comment: OK! Progress! The alertView method is getting called - I'm seeing the NSLog now in the console, but the view isn't changing.  Crazy how I have to set the delegate to "self" twice...(?).. weird

Comment: @nevan let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1202/discussion-between-truthsmiles-and-nevan)

Answer (score 0):

@PengOne's answer is correct: your problem is this:

```
if (buttonIndex = 0) {
```

You said

> I know it's not correct, but I just
>   wanted to be sure the statement was
>   true for now...

But `buttonIndex = 0` evaluates to `0`, making it equivalent to

```
if (0)
```

The code within that block will never execute, regardless of the value of buttonIndex.  If you really want to do it unconditionally, change the if to `if( 1 )`, or just take the if out.

This would have been trivial to spot if you ran this code in the debugger.  You might think you know what your code is doing, but if you don't watch it run, you don't.